# Share Calendar and Contacts

Tags: calendar, cloud-service, synchronization, contact-manager

I'm looking for a cloud tool that allows me to create contacts and calendars, just like Google.

However, I would like to share this cloud and be able to set different permissions for different users.

It should be possible to synchronize contacts and calendars with different devices (Android, iPhone).

The whole thing should be as cheap as possible, preferably free of charge.

Does anyone know a way to put my idea into practice?

Comment: Many ideas come to mind. Is it just contacts and calendars you want to "share", or also files? Depending on that, there are many solutions to self-host (Baïkal, ownCloud, Nextcloud, …) – with some even available as hosted solutions (ownCloud, Nextcloud). So is self-hosting an option? And is there anything else you wish to share apart from contacts/calendars, or would consider a "nice to have for future expansion"?

Comment: I am primarily concerned with contacts and calendars. Files would be "nice to have" but not mandatory. I don't have any experience in selfhosting yet, but I think this shouldn't be a problem, because it's only about small amounts of data.

I have already heard of ownCloud but I could not find out everything. Can I create accounts for all users and manage their rights?

Comment: By searching again I have found the information now. I will now try out nextCloud. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can see [here](/a/38960/185) and [here](/a/26107/185) for Nextcloud, the latter answer also mentions Baïkal. As you're already set for Nextcloud: you might consider to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) when you're satisfied :) Enjoy!

Comment: nextCloud works well with what I am looking for. However, I have not yet been able to find out how to revoke a user's rights. For example, a user can only see calendar entries but cannot edit them (same for contacts)

Comment: Of course, I found the setting shortly after posting the top comment.

I will, of course, still answer the question myself.

Comment: Google Calendar definitely can share calendars to any one with a google account.  You can log into your google account on an iphone.  There are a few sharing options: see only free/busy, see all details,make changes,or make changes and manage sharing